# Polyline is draw straight instead of proper driving directions route path from point A to B

Tags: google-maps, angular

I am using [angular2-google-maps](https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/index/SebmGoogleMapPolyline-directive.html) plugin with angular2

I have 2 points A & B.

I am simply trying to draw a polyline, but it draws a straight line instead of proper driving directions route.

Here is my plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Uz8Dz0zB4Ea8CJTe6wYM?p=preview

Main Code:

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="49.0096941" [longitude]="2.5457305" [zoom]="10">
     <sebm-google-map-polyline>
         <sebm-google-map-polyline-point [latitude]="49.0096941" [longitude]="2.5457305">
         </sebm-google-map-polyline-point>
         <sebm-google-map-polyline-point [latitude]="48.9688538" [longitude]="2.5375751">
         </sebm-google-map-polyline-point>
     </sebm-google-map-polyline>
   </sebm-google-map>
```

Can anyone identify the issue if any? because I am following the docs

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "proper route"?  Are you looking for the driving directions route?

Comment: @bamnet Yes I need the driving directions route

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to call the [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) to get driving directions between those two coordinates, the response will include a polyline which you can display on a map.

angular2-google-map doesn't include directive for the directions service itself, but I see plenty of example directives available in this [github issue](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/495) which should point you in the right direction.